# Jasper Report Generation Date

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I'm creating jasper report and want to print the report generation date(current) on the report? How do I do that with ireport? I hope you can help me.

Comment: Your question is not clear, anyway to show the date you can use simple static text, and if you want to print through parameter you can create a parameter and give a default date in this format -- new Date(114,02,31) for date 31-March-2014.

Answer (score 2):

Open Palette (Window->Palette) and drag "Current date" from "Tools" section to your report.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a static field and then create instance of the Date class as new Date() to print current date in desired pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your jrxml...**Cheers!** [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyr4N.jpg)

```
<textField pattern="MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a z">
            <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="280" height="21" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="3f452153-41b0-4296-84b9-5a78825a18dc"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font isItalic="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Report Generated on: "+new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<textField pattern="**dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm**">
            <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="280" height="21" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="3f452153-41b0-4296-84b9-5a78825a18dc"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>

            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Report Generated on: "+new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>`
The `new java.util.Date()` allows your to format date in a more clean way and precise.The pattern i have specified above will print `26-Oct-2017 17:50`for the 24 hour format.